# Reason behind someone's name showing up in my Activity tab

Tags: support, bug, activity-tab

[image]

I'm not sure why their name is showing in my Question activity - though they didn't take part in any of this question's life-cycle activities.

I verified this in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48156135/timeline) too, maybe some other activity will be shown to high rep guys - can you check this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That user posted an answer to the question, which was deleted:

> [image]

Since you don't have the required [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you can't see that entry on the timeline.

The date/time you see in the activity tab matches the answer's "posted" timestamp. It probably shouldn't be shown in the activity feed.

Comment: ok cool, thanks. then it should be a bug or backlog - correct?

Comment: It's either a bug, or by design...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this user posted an answer to your question which was soon deleted:

[image]

To see deleted answers (even on your own question) you need [10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: oh man, in 4 secs gap - identical answers..:)